# Classicthesis: control horizontal space between chapter number and headline on even pages

Tags: spacing, chapters, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis, and I noticed that the space between the chapter number and the headline is larger on even pages than on odd pages. How can I reduce this space so that it is about as large as on the odd pages?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,listings,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter - space is ok}
\chapter{Second chapter - space is too large}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: The space would be the same with two digit figures and utterly wrong with three digit figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classicthesis` package assumes `openright`. You can fix it:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,listings,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ttlf@chapter
  {\oldmarginpar}
  {\oldmarginpar[\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{halfgray}\hfill\chapterNumber\thechapter]}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter - space is ok}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} % just to make a fair comparison
\chapter{Second chapter - space is too large}
\end{document}
```